# What is the difference specifying abstract or not for interface methods?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

What is the difference between specifying the `abstract` keyword on a method of an interface in Java, and not specifying it?

Like:

```
public void foo();
public abstract void foo();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference. See the JLS [Interfaces - Abstract Method Declatations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html#78651):

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is **implicitly abstract**, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a block.

Also note:

> For compatibility with older versions of the Java platform, it is **permitted but discouraged**, as a matter of style, **to redundantly specify the abstract modifier** for methods declared in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference all methods in interfaces are implicit abstract because to implement that interface all methods must be overriden ...
strange that it´s working however